# Exact type constraints in generic types - C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, mapping

I want to implement a generic type mapper and I'm struggling with a problem relating to generic type constraints.

I have and entity mapper class defined below:

```
public class EntityMapper<TDto, TEntity>
{
    public void RegisterMapping<TDtoProperty, TEntityProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TDto, TDtoProperty>> expressionFrom,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntityProperty>> expressionTo,
        Func<TDtoProperty, TEntityProperty> mapper)
    {
        // mapping
    }
}
```

I also have 2 classes which properties I want to map:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long FooLongProp { get; set; }

    public decimal? FooDecimalNullProp { get; set; }

    public string FooStringProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public long? BarLongNullProp { get; set; }

    public decimal BarDecimalProp { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping is being performed as follows:

```
public void Map()
{
    var mapper = new EntityMapper<Foo, Bar>();

    mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooLongProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); // FooLongProp -> long, BarLongNullProp -> long?
    mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooDecimalNullProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); // FooDecimalNullProp -> decimal?, BarLongNullProp -> long?
    mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooDecimalNullProp, x => x.BarDecimalProp, x => x); // FooDecimalNullProp -> decimal?, BarDecimalProp -> decimal

    mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooStringProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); // FooStringProp -> string, BarLongNullProp -> long?
}
```

I want the third parameter in `RegisterMapping` to return exact the same type, as `TEntityProperty`.
Unfortunately compiler doesn't report the code for mapping between `long -> long?` below as an error. It even doesn't report error mapping `decimal? -> decimal` (which will break in the runtime).

The only place where the compiler reports error is the line where I want to cast `string -> decimal?`.

So I have following questions:

1. Why are the first 3 mappings not working as I expected? It seems
   that compiler doesn't resolve their types properly.
2. Is there any way to specify exact the same type constraint in generic constraints?
3. Is there any other possibility to achieve what I wanted to do and get errors during compilation?

Any other suggestions, comments are welcome.

Comment: Use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't do that - I need to do additional operations besides mapping. I could use automapper to perform only the mapping operation, but it would be inside of `RegisterMapping` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooLongProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); // FooLongProp -> long, BarLongNullProp -> long?
```

1. `x => x.FooLongProp` compiler infers (`Expression<Func<Foo, long>>`)
2. `x => x.BarLongNullProp` compiler infers (`Expression<Func<Bar, long?>>`)
3. `x => x` compiler infers (`Func<long, long?>>`)

---

```
mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooDecimalNullProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); // FooDecimalNullProp -> decimal?, BarLongNullProp -> long?
```

1. `x => x.FooDecimalNullProp` compiler infers (`Expression<Func<Foo, decimal?>>`)
2. `x => x` compiler infers (`Func<decimal?, decimal?>>`)!! Why?? Becuase `x=>x` is a `Func<type of x,type of x>`
3. `x => x.BarLongNullProp` compiler infers (`Expression<Func<Bar, decimal?>>`) !! Why? because of line 2 it upcast `long?` to `decimal?` so it can match the generic parameters.

---

something similar happens in other case. In the last case compiler looks for `Func<string, long?>`. when you provide `x=>x` (`Func<string,string>`) compiler can not infer the right type for your generic types so it fails. Hovering mouse cursor over the method call will reveal generic parameters inferred by compiler.  Maybe you should specify an explicit typing for your lambdas.

```
mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooLongProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => x); 
mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooDecimalNullProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => (long?)x);
mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooDecimalNullProp, x => x.BarDecimalProp, x => (decimal)x); 

mapper.RegisterMapping(x => x.FooStringProp, x => x.BarLongNullProp, x => (long?)(object)x ); //or any lambda which returns long?
```